# If it is valid that Wikipedia uses Chinese characters (and other unicode characters) in URL

Tags: url, encoding

On Wikipedia you see URLs like these:

- [https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/附录:字母索引](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%99%84%E5%BD%95:%E5%AD%97%E6%AF%8D%E7%B4%A2%E5%BC%95) (but copy-pasting the URL results in the equivalent https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%99%84%E5%BD%95:%E5%AD%97%E6%AF%8D%E7%B4%A2%E5%BC%95).
- [https://th.wiktionary.org/wiki/หน้าหลัก](https://th.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%81) (which when copy-pasted becomes
  https://th.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%81)

First, I'm wondering what is happening here, what the encoding transformation is called and what it's doing and why it's doing that. I don't see why you can't just have the original native characters in the URL.

Second, I'm wondering if what Wikipedia is doing is considered valid. If it is okay to include these non-ASCII glyphs in the URL, and if not, why not (other than perhaps because the standard says so). Also would be interested to know how many browsers support showing the link in the URL bar using the native glyphs vs. this encoded thing, and even would be interesting to know how native Chinese/Thai/etc. people enter in the URL in their language, if they use the encoding or what (but that probably makes this question too complicated; still would be an interesting bonus).

The reason I ask is because I would like to put let's say words/definitions of a few different languages onto a webpage, and I would like to make the url show the actual word used in the language. So in english it might be `/hello`, but the equivalent word/definition in Thai would be `/สวัสดี`. That makes way more sense to me than having to make it into the encoding thing.

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier

> Strings of data octets within a URI are represented as characters. *Permitted characters within a URI are the ASCII characters for the lowercase and uppercase letters of the modern English alphabet, the Arabic numerals, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.[14] Octets represented by any other character must be percent-encoded.

Not all Unicode characters can be used in URIs. Characters that aren't supported can still be encoded using [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You can see the non-ascii characters in the URL field because your browser chooses to display them that way, the actual HTTP requests are done using the encoded strings.

Comment: Note: UTF-8 is commonly applied and then %-encoding.